# How to set home directory on Alpine Linux?

Tags: user-profiles, alpine-linux

On most Linuxes one would typically use `usermod`, but Alpine doesn't seem to have it, is there some other way to set home directory on Alpine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `usermod` on Alpine, you could try installing the [`shadow`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86_64/shadow) package of the community repository:

`apk add --update shadow`

Tip: when looking for a particular Linux executable which isn't readily available on Alpine, Alpine's package search engine is very useful:
https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=usermod&path=&name=&branch=v3.10

As Alpine's popularity is steadily increasing, more and more packages are added, so there's always a good chance to find the package you're after.